# A basic question on distribution function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

The distance between two distribution functions is the infimum of those $\epsilon > 0$ such that $G(x-\epsilon) - \epsilon \leq F(x) \leq G(x+\epsilon) + \epsilon \forall x $. I want to show that $d(F,G) = 0$ implies $F=G$. How ? I don't think we can use right continuity here as it is for all $x$ we have to prove $F=G$.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$\inf \{ \epsilon \; : \; G(x-\epsilon)-\epsilon \leq F(x) \leq G(x+\epsilon) + \epsilon\},$$
there is a sequence $\epsilon_n \to 0$ such that $F(x) \leq G(x+\epsilon_n) + \epsilon_n$ holds for all $x$. Use right continuity to get $F(x) \leq G(x)$. Finally, note that $d(F,G)=d(G,F)$.